# Translating PHP’s preg_match_all to Python

Tags: php, python, regex

Can I have a translation of PHP’s `preg_match_all('/(https?:\/\/\S+)/', $text, $links)` in Python, please? (ie) I need to get the links present in the plain text argument in an array.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This will do it:

```
import re
links = re.findall('(https?://\S+)', text)
```

If you plan to use this multiple times than you can consider doing this:

```
import re
link_re = re.compile('(https?://\S+)')
links = link_re.findall(text)
```